# COUNTIFS Function for Multiple Criteria

Tags: microsoft-excel-365

I have a set of columns that look like this:

```
Keep Label
red            
blue           
green          
Yellow         
Pink
```

I want to do a `COUNTIFS` function that does a count if the row is "red", "green" or "yellow.

Expected Output:
3

Any suggestions? This is what I am using:

```
COUNTIFS(A:A,"red","green","yellow)
```

**Edit #1:**

My Original Question was Solved, but just out of curiosity, let's say I have something like this:

```
Color     person
Red       Steve
Blue      Sally
Red       Dave
Green     James
Yellow    Dave
```

I want to count the number of records in the 1st column, where the second column equals "Dave", so my expected outcome is 1.

What I tried doing was something like this:

`=SUM(COUNTIFS(A2:A5,"Red",B2:B5,"Dave"))`, but this is not working. Any suggestions?

Comment: Post this as the answer, that solved my problem. Thank you!

Comment: =COUNTIFS(A2:A5,"Red",B2:B5,"Dave")  The COUNTIFS with multiple criteria produces an array of matches, which SUM adds.  If all you need is specific matches, just remove sum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Escel-2007 and Excel-365

```
=SUM(COUNTIFS(A:A,{"red","blue","yellow"}))
```

COUNTIFS will create an array identifying matches, which SUM adds to get total.

Comment: How would that work if there were multiple columns to use as criteria?

Comment: When I try using a second column, I get a Spill Error

Comment: I edited my post. I'm going to leave this marked as the correct answer as you solved my original question, but just had a follow up on it and was curious.